# how to use createAnimatedComponent with a styled component

Tags: react-native, styled-components

whenever I use createAnimatedComponent on a styled component the way it's mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45127430/8301796).

I get this error:

> 'createAnimatedComponent' does not support stateless functional components; use a class component instead.